# Cannot build DependencyInjection package from source

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015

I have downloaded the code from https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection with Visual Studio 2015 latest CTP. I'm getting this error when trying to open the solution:

> DependencyInjection\src\Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interfaces\Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interfaces.xproj : error  : Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: projectMoniker

I googled this but I have not found any solution yet.

Also I tried to compile the code in the command line but I got a different error:

> Adding C:\Users\user.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta5-11596\bin to process PATH
>   warn: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   verbose: Stack trace:
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>     at Sake.Engine.Builder.BuilderBase`1.CallTarget(String name)

Anyone else got this working?

Comment: you did see: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/aspnetci/DependencyInjection/branch/dev build failed

Comment: you did also see: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/377 *ggrnd0 commented 26 days ago*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the first link provided by @AndreasNiedermair and tried

```
build --quiet verify
```

from the developer command prompt.

Before that I also had to rename the file at

```
$(VSToolsPath)\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props
```

to:

```
$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props
```

In order to avoid another error when loading.

Finally got it working.

Comment: you know that you can accept your own answer as a solution, which is encouraged!